# Is there a way to make a custom TextInput in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I've been trying to find a way to make a `TextInput` in Kivy with something like

```
class CustomTextInput(TextInputBehavior, Image):
    pass
```

Only that `TextInputBehavior` doesn't exist. I wonder if there's a similiar way. I've searched everywhere, the internet and the docs, just can't seem to find the right solution. By 'custom button` I mean something like this:
[image]

Comment: Does the  `hint_text` property of `TextInput` meet your needs?

Comment: There are also `background_active` and `background_normal` properties of the `TextInput` that allow you to specify background images.

Comment: i tried background_normal, it didnt make any changes.

Comment: oh, sorry, it works now. Turns out that the picture was simply too big for `background_normal` and had to be resized. Thanks a lot.